# T-SQL: Dynamic Where clause in normal SQL statement

Tags: t-sql

I looking for a way to dynamicly add a filter to my statment without using dynamic SQL.

I want to select all computers from a table, but when I pass a computer id to the sp, I want to get only this computer.

Actually I try this on

```
DECLARE @ComputerFilter AS INT
DECLARE @ComputerID AS INT

SELECT Computername 
FROM   Computer
WHERE  (ComputerID = @ComputerID) OR (@ComputerFilter IS NULL))
```

But this is 100 times slow then this statment and tooks as long as SELECT * FROM Computer

```
SELECT Computername 
FROM   Computer
WHERE  ComputerID = @ComputerID
```

Is there a way to speed this statment up or is there any other way to solve this problem with one select und without dynamic sql?

Comment: What should the system do when @ComputerFilter is not null?

Comment: Then it filters by the computerid :) Okay, I can write (ComputerID = @ComputerID) OR (@ComputerID IS NULL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DECLARE @ComputerID AS INT

```
SET @ComputerID  = null -- fro all null or just id for one

SELECT Computername 
FROM   Computer
WHERE  ComputerID = ISNULL( @ComputerID, ComputerID  )
```

When you dont need

Comment: Hi, nice solution, thank you. But the server makes an Index Scan too. Maybe I've to use two statement to get performance :(

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way would be to use `IF` statement.

```
IF @ComputerID IS NULL BEGIN
  SELECT Computername 
  FROM   Computer
END
ELSE BEGIN
  SELECT Computername 
  FROM   Computer
  WHERE  ComputerID = @ComputerID
END
```

Comment: This seems like the simplest option.

Comment: I agree IMO IF / ELSE is the best solution. @grzegorz, you here?! :)

Comment: Yes. I am. Since SO private beta.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server is often bad at optimising queries with an `OR` in the `WHERE` clause. Sometimes a `UNION` or `UNION ALL` is better. In your case, perform the `@ComputerFilter IS NULL` check first in in `IF` statement, and just do a `SELECT` without a `WHERE` if true...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have indexing on the table?  That should help performance.

Comment: Yes, but the SQL Server only use it when I use the second statement. When I use my first stamtement with the "filter" the server makes an Index Scan.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "one size fits all" query approach for this, there are subtle performance implications in how you do this. If you would like to go beyond just making the query return the proper answer, no matter how slow it is, look at this article on [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQLby Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)